# Keras-Tuner: Is it possible to use test/validation set in the objective/metric function?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, keras-tuner

Is it possible to score/evaluate the model performance, using `keras-tuner`, based on the test set instead of the training set? I'm asking this, because as of now, my understanding is that the metric function used as objective in the `tuner.search()` uses only `y_true` and `y_pred` as the input parameters, and they both refer to the training set (correct me if I'm wrong).
So how can I use test data in my metric function?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you cannot, neither should you, use test data metrics during hyper-parameter tuning.  [KerasTuner](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/keras_tuner?hl=uk) allows you to use validation data metrics as the objective, which I encourage.  However, the final test should always be done after all tuning and training is complete, and should use none of the training or validation data.

To use a validation metric, simply tell KT that its objective is something beginning with `val` in the name.